# How to put a div inside a Switch with React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an APP using React and Redux, and I wanted to load a `NotFound` component when the user enters an invalid route. I found online a way to solve that problem, that is by putting all the routes inside a switch, including the `NotFound` component.

The problem is that, in my app, I can't put all my routes inside a Switch because There is a single component that needs to be stretched to the entire page, while all the other components need to be inside a "container". The way I have it below (see the code), the `NotFound` component works for all cases, except when I'm on the "landing" component route (where the `NotFound` component always displays).

I tried to put the landing component inside the `Switch` with the "container" div but the app crashes.

Is there any way to solve this? (keeping the landing component out of the container, and the other components inside)

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <div className="container">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
                <Route exact path="/profile/:handle" component={Profile} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/create-profile"
                  component={CreateProfile}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/edit-profile"
                  component={EditProfile}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/add-experience"
                  component={AddExperience}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/add-education"
                  component={AddEducation}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/edit-education/:id"
                  component={EditEducation}
                />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/feed" component={Posts} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
              </Switch>
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a separate router for all other components except landing page.

```
// App.js
import NonLandingPages from './NonLandingPages';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                <Route component={NonLandingPages}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Separate router for all other pages

```
// NonLandingPages.js
class NonLandingPages extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
                <Route exact path="/profile/:handle" component={Profile} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/create-profile"
                  component={CreateProfile}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/edit-profile"
                  component={EditProfile}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/add-experience"
                  component={AddExperience}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/add-education"
                  component={AddEducation}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  exact
                  path="/edit-education/:id"
                  component={EditEducation}
                />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/feed" component={Posts} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```