# React Router 404 - NotFound page does not show

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react router switch and the 404 page doesnt work

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
 <Layout>
  <ProtectedRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
  <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
  <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profiles/alarms" component={Alarms} />
  <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profiles/:id" component={Profile} />
 </Layout>
 <ProtectedRoute component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Whenever I change the url to a random one like '/tewyu'. The page just shows blank it doesnt go to the 404 page. It feels like one of the routes are catching it

Comment: Is that your full router code? Have you used the react-dev-tool to see what route/component ***is*** being rendered?

Comment: A null component is rendered. These specific routes work however but not the 404 page. Also I have the swtch wrapper in a browser router

Comment: Interesting. Can you try creating a *running* condesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can live debug in?

Comment: I also just realized I have a navbar that is wrapping some routes inside of my switch is that fine? @DrewReese

Comment: I tried remaking an example on codesandbox but cant reproduce its something worng with my app :/

Comment: Are other routes like `/home`, `/profile` etc. working? You have problem only with "NotFound" route?

Comment: No, only `Route` or `Redirect` components are valid children of a `Switch`. Can you update your question to include your actual code, please? Once we see the real code we can help restructure it so a nested navbar works.

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the question to show what it looks like

Comment: @AjeetShah those routes are working its just not going to the 404 not found apge

Comment: @ousmane784 what is the code of <ProtectedRoute> ?

Comment: Its a huge codebase to put in here but basically Layout contains a navbar with the current page underneath with properly spaced layout. The protected route just redirects to login if user is inauthenticated. Making NotFound a protected route would still show the navbar with 404 page underneath it

Comment: Im just wondering why at a random route, it would render a null component

Comment: It could possibly be an issue with your `ProtectedRoute` component, can you share `ProtectedRoute` code in your question?

Comment: Here is a duplicate issue: [How to put a div inside a Switch with React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52389113/2873538)

Comment: @AjeetShah thats works! Unlinke the other question however, I just took out the login route from the switch and wrapped the switch in Layout. Would the login route still work if it doesnt need a switch?

Comment: I don't fully get what you did. Can you edit your question and put a heading `### Edit:` and put your latest attempt under it? `Login` route should not work if it is not inside a `Switch`. Does it work?

Comment: @AjeetShah The login route would still be inclusively matched by being rendered within a `Router` component. `Switch` just modifies the matching behavior to do exclusive matching.

Comment: @DrewReese, Hi bro.. Could you find some time to help me out in this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610432/13270726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have two basic views, your app with a navbar and specific layout, and a authentication page.

You can wrap the nested `Layout` component in a general route and render the nested routes into another `Switch` for matching.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route>
    <Layout> // <-- navbar and layout
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profiles/alarms" component={Alarms} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profiles/:id" component={Profile} />
        <ProtectedRoute component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Of course, you could also make the general `Route` component a `ProtectedRoute` and then render normal `Route` components within this auth "checkpoint".

Comment: Does Layout need to be wrapped in a Route component? I tried without it and it still works

Comment: @ousmane784 Well, it technically should be in a `Route` but it is working because the outer `Switch` hits and returns `Layout`. If you had any routes afterwards though, they would not be reachable. That said, with this general route that matches everything anyway then any routes specified after wouldn't/couldn't be reached either so I guess it's still about the same.